# In jquery, how can I detect if a paragraph contains one link and only one link, nothing else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply a class 'solo' to a link in a paragraph where that link is the ONLY element in the paragraph.

So this  would get the 'solo' class:

```
<p><a>I am alone</a></p>
```

But this  would not:

```
<p><a>I am not alone</a> because there is more text!</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    var $childNodes = $(this).contents();

    return $childNodes
             .not($childNodes.filter('a').first())
             .not(function() {
                 return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) === '';
             }).length === 0;
});
```

This gets all child nodes (including text nodes) and removes the first `a` element it finds and all text nodes only containing whitespaces from that set. If the resulting set is empty, the link was the only child (alone).

**Reference**: [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType), [`trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

**Update:** Maybe this could be done easier, but I wanted it to work also for the case your HTML contains line breaks, which would result in text nodes containing only whitespaces:

```
<p>
    <a>I am alone</a>
</p>

<p>
    <a>I am not alone</a> because there is more text!
</p>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HDQsr/3/)

Comment: @Felix: Can you explain why you didn't choose (something along the lines of)... `return $(this).contents().length === 1 && $(this).contents().is('a');` ?

Comment: @Matt: I wanted to account for "empty" text nodes as well, like when you have a line break after the opening `<p>` tag. There might be simpler ways, this was just my train of thoughts.

Comment: If you just use contents() instead of children() it's much easier and compact http://jsfiddle.net/VPp7B/

Comment: @Davide: But it won't work with line breaks anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/VPp7B/1/, and I do think (or hope) people use line breaks in their HTML to make it more readable.

Comment: @Matt: I changed the code a bit so that it is hopefully easier to understand and more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    var $childrens = $(this).children();
    return ($childrens.length == 1 
            && $childrens.is('a') 
            && $(this).text() == $childrens.text());
}).addClass('solo');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EKxbf/)**

Comment: That won't recognize text nodes.

Comment: @FelixKling - Modified my answer with demo

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 more way to do this:

```
if($("p").find('a').length === 1){
   //perform operation
}
```

Comment: I think its already being told. I think I repeated the answer

Comment: As I commented on other answers, this won't give the expected results as you are not considering text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Not very performant, but this is the most concise and nice (and working) solution I came out with!

```
$('p').filter( function() {
    return !$('<p>'+$.trim($(this).html())+'</p>').contents().not('a:first').length;
}).addClass('solo');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DYxgu/